# on ajax success action create new model of json data and pass that model to the view

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, asp.net-mvc

if I have ajax request like this

```
$.ajax({
        dataType: "json",
        url: "http://www.omdbapi.com/?i=tt0111161",
        success: function (data) {  
           // create new MyModel and pass that to the view

        }
    })
```

is it possible to use response data for create new model and pass that into view where which will be used as normal Model.Something

for example, I have html snippet

```
<div id="tab" class="tab-pane">
       @Html.Partial("_TabPartial", Model)
</div>
```

Model is of type MyModel. Is it possible after successfull ajax response to create new `MyModel` object and pass that on the view for use on _TabPartial?

Comment: Unclear what your asking. Are you wanting to update the form controls generated by `@Html.Partial()` with the data returned in your ajax call?

Comment: Yes, I want to update labels and all other form controlls together with data itself.

Comment: The you need `$(someElement).val(data.someProperty);` to update the values of for controls. Not sure what you mean by _update labels_. A label is for the name of the field (associated with a form control), it should not be changed)